# Version Download Protocol JWS

Tags: java, java-web-start

I deployed a Java Web Start application using the JWS Version Download Protocol as outlined on [Avoiding Unnecessary Update Checks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/avoidingUnnecessaryUpdateChecks.html).

According to this manual, JWS should check in the background if the version number has changed and download the new app if necessary. But it does not work for me - a check of my server logfiles shows that JWS doesn't even connect to the server, so the client will never know that there is a newer version available.

This is the main JNLP file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- JNLP File for PEE Mail Client -->
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://www.peemail.org/home/projects/pee/beta/" >
    <!-- information -->
    <information>
        <title>PEE Mail</title>
        <vendor>Andreas Junius, Software Engineer</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.peemail.org/" />
        <description>PEE - Privacy Enhanced Email</description>
        <icon kind="shortcut" href="stamp16x16.png" width="16" height="16" />
        <icon kind="default" href="stamp32x32.png" width="32" height="32" />
        <icon kind="shortcut" href="stamp32x32.png" width="32" height="32" />
        <icon kind="splash" href="javanerd_500x290.png" width="500"
        height="290" />
        <shortcut online="true" install="true">
            <desktop />
            <menu submenu="Javanerd" />
        </shortcut>
        <offline-allowed />
    </information>
    <!-- full access required -->
    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>
    <!-- check always for updates -->
    <update check="background" policy="always" />
    <!-- resources -->
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8+" />
        <jar href="peemail.jar" main="true" download="eager" size="1143096" version="01.00.66" />
        <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>
        <!-- cryptographic libraries -->
        <extension name="BouncyCastle cryptography library" href="bcprov.jnlp" />
        <extension name="BouncyCastle pkix library" href="bcpkix.jnlp" />
    </resources>
    <!-- main class -->
    <application-desc main-class="org.peemail.client.swing.PeeMain" />  
</jnlp>
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: A nice tool, thanks for that. Unfortunately it didn't help me to solve that particular problem ( I made a few changes).

An odd thing is that the versioning works for the extensions, but not for the main jnlp. The console says:

`CacheEntry[http://www.peemail.org/bcprov.jnlp]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Thu Jan 01 09:30:00 ACST 1970,length=633
CacheEntry[http://www.peemail.org/bcpkix.jnlp]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Thu Jan 01 09:30:00 ACST 1970,length=618`

And I can see that the server gets asked for these two, but not for the main jnlp.